# For each x in column 1, put a y in column 2

Tags: pandas, match, variable-assignment

I have two separate columns `names` and `IDs`, in two separate excel workbooks.

```
Column 1 
     
550

550

450

550 


Column 2 (in a different excel workbook)

Jane

Bob
```

In a new excel workbook, I would like to create two separate columns for `name` and `ID`. For every 550 in column 1, I would like to put 'Jane' in a column 2, and for ever 450 in column 2, I would like to put Bob. I do not have a working code drafted yet, is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you are doing this in Excel, use `VLOOKUP`. If you doing this in Python / pandas, use `map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. If you are new to Python/Pandas, I would just do something simple like copy your `id` column into a new column called `name` and then replace the values.

Here is what this looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

### Make up data, you would probably just 
### import this from your Excel file
colA = [550, 550, 450, 550]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(colA)), columns =['ids']) 

df['names'] = df['ids']
df.replace({'names': {550: 'Bob', 450: 'Jane'}}, inplace=True)
display(df)
```

[image]

Another way, as mentioned in the comments, is to use a dictionary to "map" it:

```
mydict = {550:'Bob', 450:'Jane'}
df['using_map'] = df['ids'].map(mydict)
display(df)
```

[image]